# There is a way to send a notification every 4 hours with local notifications?

Tags: flutter, dart, notifications, flutter-local-notification

I'm wondering if there is a way to send a notification every 4 hours with `flutter_local_notifications`.

This package have a repeat notification utility but you have to choose between a repeat interval, but it only provides 4 choices:

`RepeatInterval.everyMinute`
`RepeatInterval.hourly`
`RepeatInterval.daily`
`RepeatInterval.weekly`

A code snippet:

```
Future<void> _repeatNotification() async {
    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails =
        AndroidNotificationDetails(
            'repeating channel id', 'repeating channel name',
            channelDescription: 'repeating description');
    const NotificationDetails notificationDetails =
        NotificationDetails(android: androidNotificationDetails);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.periodicallyShow(
      id++,
      'repeating title',
      'repeating body',
      RepeatInterval.hourly, // <-- HERE
      notificationDetails,
      androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
    );
  }
```

Someone know if there is a way to repeat with a precise amount of hours instead a generic "hourly"? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use either of these packages:

1. https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager
2. https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch

These packages allow you to schedule background tasks in your app.

Then you can use `flutter_local_notifications` package to trigger a notification as part of the task.